# What performance strategies can be used to handle both old and new accounting balance?

Tags: database, database-design

Our current approach is using a view (eg: view_calculated_invoices) to calculate and return all invoices' current balance. Our database has grown significantly and performance starts to suffer.

As you can imagine, ***older invoices can afford stale data*** because the data hardly changes after the invoice is paid in full. ***Newer invoices are very active and will need to remain fresh*** (eg: applying for payments and/or applying late fees).

What performance strategies should be considered to maintain a mix of old (less refresh needed) vs new invoices (frequent refresh needed)?

We are using Postgresql v10.

We have tried to use materialized view but it didn't work out because we needed to refresh the data too frequently due to the activity of newer invoices.

We created a table to maintain the result of the view_calculated_invoices query and update a single invoice every time there is a change (delete or update) but it has caused us a lot of problems. It is a makeshift strategy but we are now ready to consider professional and better strategies.